# ReactJS HREF Causes State Loss

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-state-management, react-state

I have a parent component called EnrollForm with a BrowserRouter that routes to different sub-components which are the pages of my overall EnrollForm.

Each time a sub-component page is filled out and next btn is clicked, all form fields are saved to sub-component state obj, then that state is passed to the parent EnrollForm state. This flow is working correctly.. however when I added the line of code to href to the next sub-component, the parent EnrollForm state is deleted and so is BioForm's state.

Any help would be so greatly appreciated, It's probably simple but I've been looking at it for so long...

EnrollForm Component:

```
class EnrollForm extends Component {
    state = {

    }

    setParentFormState = (newStateObj, fromComponent) => {
        this.setState({...this.state, ...newStateObj}, () => {
            console.log('Updated EnrollForm component state from ' + fromComponent);
            console.log(this.state);
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Router>
                <div className='workflow'>
                    <Route path='/enrollment-form/bio' render={(routeProps)=>(<BioForm {...routeProps} setParentFormState={this.setParentFormState}/>)}/>
                    <Route path='/enrollment-form/citizenship' render={(routeProps)=>(<CitizenshipForm {...routeProps} setParentFormState={this.setParentFormState}/>)}/>
                    <Route path='/enrollment-form/identity' render={(routeProps)=>(<IdentityForm {...routeProps} setParentFormState={this.setParentFormState}/>)}/>
                    <Route path='/enrollment-form/attributes' render={(routeProps)=>(<AttributesForm {...routeProps} setParentFormState={this.setParentFormState}/>)}/>
                    <Route path='/enrollment-form/address' render={(routeProps)=>(<AddressForm {...routeProps} setParentFormState={this.setParentFormState}/>)}/>
                    <Route path='/enrollment-form/eligibility' render={(routeProps)=>(<EligibilityForm {...routeProps} setParentFormState={this.setParentFormState}/>)}/>
                    <Route path='/enrollment-form/documents' render={(routeProps)=>(<DocumentsForm {...routeProps} setParentFormState={this.setParentFormState}/>)}/>
                    <Route path='/enrollment-form/location' render={(routeProps)=>(<LocationForm {...routeProps} setParentFormState={this.setParentFormState}/>)}/>
                    <Route path='/enrollment-form/appointment' render={(routeProps)=>(<ApptTimeForm {...routeProps} setParentFormState={this.setParentFormState}/>)}/>
                    <Route path='/enrollment-form/status' render={(routeProps)=>(<StatusForm {...routeProps} setParentFormState={this.setParentFormState}/>)}/>
                </div>
            </Router>
        );
    }
}

export default EnrollForm;
```

BioForm Component:

```
class BioForm extends Component {
    state = {
        first_name: null,
        middle_name: null,
        last_name: null,
        u_suffix: null,
        u_gender: null,
        u_dob: null,
        u_lang: null,
        u_email: null,
        u_country_code_1: null,
        u_country_code_2: null,
        u_phone_1: null,
        u_phone_2: null,
        u_contact_method: null

    }

    nextButtonClicked = event => {
        let form = document.getElementById('applicant-form');
        let formDataJsObj = FormFunctions.getJsObjFromFormData(form);
        let keyToDelete = 'u_email[verify]';
        //This field is removed from the form data object because it is not sent in the POST request
        FormFunctions.removeKeyFromFormObj(formDataJsObj, keyToDelete);
        console.log(formDataJsObj);
        this.setState(formDataJsObj, () => {
            this.props.setParentFormState(this.state, this.constructor.name);
            console.log('BioForm data submitted and parent state updated.. changing pages.');
            window.location.href = '/enrollment-form/citizenship';
        });



    }
    render(){//markup}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This cause a page reload, which reset your all you states (Redux included) and render everything again:

```
window.location.href = '/enrollment-form/citizenship';
```

Replace it by:

```
this.props.history.push('/enrollment-form/citizenship')
```

Note that you might need to wrap your component with *withRouter* like this:

```
export default withRouter(EnrollForm);
```

With the import:

```
import { withRouter } from "react-router";
```

Hope it helps. Happy coding!

Comment: Thank you very much sir for you answer which worked perfect for me. It would seem there are more things I need to know about React! I'm not sure why this works, but it does. I also tried using <link> with to and onClick events, but the page would just redirect before the event handler ran! I'll have to figure that out as well.

Comment: it's probably because you did onClick={yourFunc} instead of onClick={()=>yourFunc}

Answer (score 0):

Never use href with react, instead use  for declarative change route, or wrap component in [withRouter](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter) and use history.push for imperative change

Comment: I tried using declarative routing with <Link to='' onClick={}> but the page just rdeirects before the event handler fires. Thanks for the info! It's working now with history.push.