# React.js: State not getting update before url redirect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a `currentUser` object in `App.state` that starts out as an empty object before the user is logged in and gets set with the user's information once the user successfully logs in.

Upon a successful login, I call `setState({currentUser: user})` which prompts an update. Then, in `componentDidUpdate()`, I check whether a change to `currentUser` prompted the update, and if it did, I call `window.location.href = "/home"`, and render a `<Home />` component.

```
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    // if the user just successfully logged in, redirect to home
    if (
      Object.keys(prevState.currentUser).length === 0 && // was an empty object
      Object.keys(this.state.currentUser).length > 0 // now it's been set
    ) {
      window.location.href = "/home"; // render the Home component, passing this.state.currentUser as a prop
    }
  }
```

in `render()`:

```
  <Route
    path="/home"
    render={(props) => (
      <Home currentUser={this.state.currentUser} />
    )}
  />
```

The problem is, when the user gets redirected to `/home`, `this.props.currentUser` is still an empty object in the `Home.props`. So even though an update to `this.state.currentUser` (where it explicitly isn't an empty object anymore) is what triggered the change to the `/home` Route, `this.state.currentUser` is still an empty object when I pass it down as a prop.

What am I misunderstanding here?

Comment: Afaik you're not supposed to change location.href directly; doing that will completely discard your app state and start over (because the browser moves to another location).

Comment: You can programmatically navigate using `this.props.history.push('/home')`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Programmatically navigate using react router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31079081/programmatically-navigate-using-react-router)

Comment: you might want to use `this.props.history.push()` if you are using react-router

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`window.location.href` is a valid way to change the route. However, this actually causes a reload or a refresh of the entire page. It is similar to how you manually type this url in the browser. Therefore, all the states are removed or cleared.

As suggested in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59417162/reactjs-href-causes-state-loss), you are supposed to use the following:

`this.props.history.push('/home')`

And in order to pass parameters, you may check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44121069/how-to-pass-params-with-history-push-link-redirect-in-react-router-v4)

Comment: Thanks! Just started learning how to use Routers, this was very helpful.